# Add product to cart in Firefox (virtuemart)

Tags: firefox, virtuemart

I've tested in Chrome and IE, both work fine.  I've added the following to my internal htaccess.txt file:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.clothdiaperu.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.clothdiaperu.com/$1 [R=301,L]

I've also removed "return false" from the two places it could be run in the theme I am using.  I've tried removing other pieces that I thought in the past were conflicting.  Nothing works.  My website is

http://www.clothdiaperu.com

You do not have to login to attempt to add products to the cart.  The main problem is selecting a child product, then adding it to the cart.  Here is a direct link to a product that doesn't add to the cart in Firefox:

http://www.clothdiaperu.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.pbv.v2.tpl&product_id=38&category_id=5&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of FF are you using? I just tried it with 3.5.6 and it works for me.

Comment: I fixed it a little while back, forgot to close it up.  The problem was the opposite of what I've read and been told, and had to ENABLE Ajax.  It seems there are lots of problems relating to this almost every release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it a little while back, forgot to close it up. The problem was the opposite of what I've read and been told, and had to ENABLE Ajax. It seems there are lots of problems relating to this almost every release.